# C++ MFC CStringList - Memory clean up, possible memory leaks

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using a [`CStringList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstringlist-class?view=msvc-170) object. I am wondering whether my code may result in memory leaks or not because of how I manipulate this list.

I have a class member variable:

`CStringList m_ListOfSz;`

I use the `AddTail()` function to add `CString` objects to the list:

```
CString sz1 = "A string 1";
CString sz2 = "A string 2";
m_ListOfSz.AddTail(sz1);
m_ListOfSz.AddTail(sz2);
```

At some point in the program, I use the `RemoveAll()` function to remove all the `CString` objects I added to the list.

As I didn't allocate memory for these `CString` objects, I don't have to free memory related to them, or do I?

Can I rely on the system to clean up the memory properly?

Comment: Yes you can rely on them to be deallocated correctly. Of course as a C++ programmer you should be using `std::vector<std::string>` instead of obsolete, inferior and platform specific code.

Comment: @john There's **nothing** portable about `std::string`. It's literally inferior to *any* string type C++ has to offer.

Comment: Do you fill the list in a worker thread and read it back in the UI thread? CStringList is not threadsafe, so it may be leak from there.

Comment: @TomTom If you write from one thread and read from another thread, the reader might observe a wrong state, but there will be no leaks.

Comment: @IInspectable I have no idea what you mean. Could you explain? Why is `std::string` not portable? What alternative superior string types does C++ offer?

Comment: @john `std::string` uses *some*, unspecified character encoding. Just because using a `std::string` will compile for multiple platforms doesn't magically make the code exhibit the same behavior. `std::wstring` is superior in that it uses UTF-16 by convention, on Windows. There are also `std::u8string` and `std::u16string`, which, again, are meant to use a specific character encoding, by convention.

Comment: @IInspectable That all fair comment, but does not mean that std::string is non-portable, or that it has different behaviour on different platforms. The behaviour is well defined by C++ standards. That the behaviour does not include a character encoding is arguably a weakness but that is all.

Answer (score 4):

> As I didn't allocate memory for these `CString` objects, I don't have to free memory related to them, or do I?

No, you do not.  Since you are not allocating any dynamic memory yourself for the objects, there is nothing for you to free.

Creating a `CString` will allocate memory internally for itself as needed. When the `CString` is destroyed, it frees any memory that it had allocated.

Adding strings to a `CStringList` will likewise allocate memory internally as needed. When strings are removed from the list, or the list is destroyed, it will free the relevant memory that it had allocated.

All of this is managed automatically for you.

> Can I rely on the system to clean up the memory properly?

Typically yes, if you are using the objects correctly.

Leaks can only occur if you create the objects dynamically and don't destroy them.

Your example does not appear to be doing that, at least not directly.  It is creating the `CString`/`List` objects in automatic memory, so their lifetimes are managed by the compiler, which will handle the necessary cleanup for you when they go out of scope.

However, your `m_ListOfSz` object is a member of a class. If that class is created dynamically, then `m_ListOfSz` and all of its stored `CString`s *can* be leaked if that class object is not destroyed properly.  There is not enough context in your post to determine is that is actually the case or not.

Comment: That's somewhat misleading. `CString sz1 = "A string 1";` *does* allocate memory (even if it is managed automatically). `AddTail()`, again, allocates memory for a copy. Once everything is said and done, the initial `CString`'s destructor will release its memory, leaving the `CStringList` as the sole owner of of the copy, which gets freed when any of the `RemoveXyz()` members is called, or when its destructor runs. The observable behavior is as if no allocations were made, but the description of the details is off target.

Comment: Sure, the `CString` allocates dynamic memory internally as needed. But the user's code is not allocating its own dynamic memory with `new` or equivalent, so there is nothing for the user's code to free. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That's better. Might want to add an answer to the literal question: *"Can I rely on the system to clean up the memory properly?"*, which is an unconditional *"Yes"*.

Comment: It is not *unconditional*, though. `m_ListOfSz` is a member of a class.  If that class is created dynamically, then `m_ListOfSz` and all of its stored `CString`s *can* be leaked, if that class is not destroyed properly. I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

The `CString` objects indeed allocate memory to store the string contents (the "buffer"). This memory is released by their destructors. Also, the `CStringList` destructor will destroy its items in the list. So to answer your question, no, you don't need to release anything yourself, they will all be released when the `CStringList` object gets out of scope (or you call `delete`, if it was created by calling `new`).